Looking for a manga where fl turns back time to save the ml
So i read this manga a long time ago like a year or something. It was a historical manga where fl engagement gets broken and then kicked out. Then she goes to neighboring country. There she accidentally meets that country prince and falls in love. Then some issues happens that prevents them being together everything suddenly takes turn for worse. So the fl turns back on time to save everyone. She promised herself not to meet the prince again but it happens. That's all I remember.

Do you recall the hair colour of the female lead and/or the prince?

Not Revolutionary Princess Eve?

@FuzzyBoots - No broken engagement or kicking out in that one. Also no journey to a neighbouring country or meeting with a foreign prince. At least, not in the early chapters. Plus, it's the male lead who turns back time, not the female lead.

@LogicDictates sorry can't remember
